# How can I use a for loop for two roles on a role.members usage

Tags: discord.py

So I have been trying to create a command where I can run the command **"-roster Arizona Cardinals"** as an example. And what it will do is return a list of mentions, and name#discriminators of the members within  the Arizona Cardinals Role. But the Issue I have been stuck with, is When I am trying to return the Franchise Owner, General Manager, and Head Coach User mentions within the cardinals role, I cannot seem to do it without breaking the for loop for the `for member in role.members` Here is a snippet of where I am attempting to troubleshoot.

```py
@commands.Command()
  async def roster(ctx, role: discord.Role=None):
    em = discord.Embed(title=f"{role.name}\'s Current Team Roster:", color=role.color)
    em.set_author()
    fo=discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles,id=846618354478481409)
    gm=discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles,id=846618640957833259)
    hc=discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles,id=846618777213730837)
    for member in role.members:
      embed.add_field(name="\u200b",
                      value=f"{member.mention}\n"
                      f"`{member.name}#{member.discriminator}`"
      )
```

Comment: Let me know if I need to send a larger snippet by the way!

Answer (score 0):

Wait, I think if I just add a item loop (e.g `member = [member for member in role.members]`) and then the franchise owner general manager and head coach user mentions. then finish the loop with:
`embed.add_field(name="\u200b", value=f"{member.mention}\n {member.name}#{member.discriminator}")`
that should work if I am correct? Am I not? So my finishing snippet would be:

```py
@commands.Command()
async def roster(ctx, role: discord.Role=None):
  em = discord.Embed(title=f"{role.name}\'s Current Team Roster:", color=role.color)
  em.set_author()
  fo=discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles,id=846618354478481409)
  gm=discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles,id=846618640957833259)
  hc=discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles,id=846618777213730837)
  for role in ctx.guild.roles:
    member = [member for member in role.members]
    if role == fo:
      em.add_field(name="**__Franchise Owner__**:", value=f"{member.mention}\n"
      f"`{member.name}#{member.discriminator}`"
      )
    elif role == gm:
. . .
    else:
      em.add_field(name="\u200b", value=f"{member.mention}\n"
      f"`{member.name}#{member.discriminator}`"
      )
```